# how to start a function using a Struct?

Tags: c

So I have to read a binary file full of structs like this:

```
typedef struct {
    char name[50];
    int a,b,c;
    int no_args;
}   func;
```

An imported header file has functions like:

```
void add(int,int);
void min(int,int);
void doSomething();
```

now the function name will always be like add    /   min   /  doSomething ... 
and the arguments of add are (a,b), and arguments of min are (b,c).

So how would I be able to start these functions, a map maybe to a function ?
I want to do this so I can benchmark my functions using the same large binary file.
How would I go about doing this in C ? This is a simple version of my program.

```
func f = {"add",5,8,9,0};
```

now I need to start the function `add(a,b);`

Comment: When you compile a C program, `add` as a declared function name is handled by the compiler in a symbol table. The compiled binary code knows nothing about the function actually being called by the string "add". Conversely, you can't take a string in C and convert it to the address that the linker has assigned to the original token, `add`. What you can do is declare a function type inside a struct and then directly assign `add` to it.

Comment: You are. writing an interpreter for a language that has instructions"add", etc.

Answer (score 2):

> I need to start the function add(a,b) ;

You probably mean that "you need to *call* the function *named* `add`".

At runtime, the name of functions in a C or C++ program don't matter anymore (and conceptually do not exist). There is even a Unix utility, called [strip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strip_(Unix)), to remove every name (and all the symbol tables) inside an [executable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable).

So you could do the following: construct a data structure associating names (e.g. strings like `add`) to [*function pointers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_pointer). For instance, you might first define a type for the signature of `add` and `sub`:

```
typedef int sig2t (int, int);
```

Then, fill an array with both names and function pointers; first declare its type:

```
struct funbind_st {
  const char*fname;
  sig2t* faddr;
};
```

And the array:

```
const struct funbind_st funbindings[] = {
 { "add", add },
 { "sub", sub },
 { NULL, (sig2t*)0 }
};
```

Of course, you'll better have `doSomething` of the *same* (and common) signature `sig2t`. And in practice, you probably want something more efficient (perhaps some [hash-table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) associating names to function pointers).

Then, finding in that `funbindings` the element of `fname` the `"sub"` string is a simple exercise (you'll need `strcmp` to compare strings).

---

On Linux specifically, there is another way, which uses the [dynamic linker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_linker) (taking advantage of the [symbol table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) of your executable), that is the [dlopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) and [dlsym(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlsym.3.html) functions from the `-ldl` library.

You first need to link your entire program with something like `gcc -rdynamic *.o -ldl -o yourprog`

Then you get the program handle (in your C code) using:

```
void* proghdl = dlopen(NULL, RTLD_NOW);
if (!proghdl) {
  fprintf(stderr, "dlopen program failed %s\n", dlerror());
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

then, you could get (into some function pointer `addptr`) the address of the *global* function named `"add"` with

```
sig2t*addptr = (sig2t*) dlsym(proghdl, "add");
if (!addptr) {
  fprintf(stderr, "dlsym add failed %s\n", dlerror());
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

For details, read the documentation and Drepper's [*How to write shared libraries*](https://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf) paper.

Read [SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/), and read more about [closures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)) (you'll need to define your implementation of closures, since C don't have any) and [callbacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_(computer_programming)). You probably need to have them.

---

> I want to do this so I can benchmark my functions using the same large binary file.

Why does that need to be a binary file. If you want to benchmark a large library with many functions, you are perhaps using the wrong approach. Did you consider instead embedding an interpreter in your program (like [lua](https://lua.org/) or [guile](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/))? Then your benchmarking file would be some script in that interpreter! Of course that interpreter has its own overhead, so you need to be sure that each function is benchmarked against a large enough case (e.g. every function benchmark needs to take deciseconds, not microseconds, to run).

Comment: This is all good, but given that the OP does not seem to have his structures stored in a table, don't you think it would be easier for him to skip the name-binding altogether and just use function pointers alone?  Only if the functions to be called are not linked into the executable (so that `dlopen` / `dlsym` are required) does the rest of it seem sensible to me.

Comment: The OP's question has an `"add"` *string*

Comment: BTW, `dlsym` on the result of `dlopen(NULL, RTLD_NOW)` is looking inside the symbol table of the executable.

Comment: Indeed he does.  I'm suggesting that perhaps he really wants (just) a function pointer instead.

Comment: Apparently, the `"add"` *name* is a string read from some binary file. I won't recommend storing function addresses inside a binary file (it would be *very* brittle)

Comment: Ah, I overlooked the "read from a file" part.  I agree, using pointers read from a file would not be advisable.